# My code works but the setters don't create new objects so I get the wrong results

Tags: c++

So whenever I post the following code I get the wrong responses,
The class member variables do get updated with my setters, but for some reason the final cost is incorrect. I am not allowed to change the main.cpp codes

I am thinking that it might be something with the setters but I can't figure out how to force the setters to invoke the constructor so the setTotalCost() can get invoked

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Inventory.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << fixed
         << showpoint
         << setprecision(2);

    // Demonstrate the default constructor
    Inventory stockItem1;
    cout << "\nDemonstrating the default constructor...\n";
    cout << "Item number: " << stockItem1.getItemNumber() << endl;
    cout << "Quantity   : " << stockItem1.getQuantity() << endl;
    cout << "Cost       : " << stockItem1.getCost() << endl;
    cout << "Total Cost : " << stockItem1.getTotalCost() << endl;

    // Now demonstrate the overloaded constructor
    Inventory stockItem2(124, 12, 84.95);
    cout << "\nDemonstrating the overloaded constructor...\n";
    cout << "Item number: " << stockItem2.getItemNumber() << endl;
    cout << "Quantity   : " << stockItem2.getQuantity() << endl;
    cout << "Cost       : " << stockItem2.getCost() << endl;
    cout << "Total Cost : " << stockItem2.getTotalCost() << endl;

    // Now demonstrate the member "set" functions
    stockItem2.setItemNumber(243);
    stockItem2.setQuantity(50);
    stockItem2.setCost(9.50);
    cout << "\nDemonstrating the \"set\" functions...\n";
    cout << "Item number: " << stockItem2.getItemNumber() << endl;
    cout << "Quantity   : " << stockItem2.getQuantity() << endl;
    cout << "Cost       : " << stockItem2.getCost() << endl;
    cout << "Total Cost : " << stockItem2.getTotalCost() << endl;

    // Now demonstrate the input validation functions
    cout << "\nDemonstrating the input validation functions...\n";
    stockItem2.setItemNumber(-1);
    stockItem2.setQuantity(-1);
    stockItem2.setCost(-1);

    cout << "\nItem number: " << stockItem2.getItemNumber() << endl;
    cout << "Quantity   : " << stockItem2.getQuantity() << endl;
    cout << "Cost       : " << stockItem2.getCost() << endl;
    cout << "Total Cost : " << stockItem2.getTotalCost() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Inventory.h

```
//Header File

#include<iostream>
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

class Inventory
{
private:
    int itemNumber;
    int quantity;
    double cost;
    double totalCost;

public:
    // default constructor, setting all values to 0
    Inventory();
    Inventory(int, int, double);
    void setItemNumber(int );
    void setQuantity(int );
    void setCost(double );
    void setTotalCost();
    int getItemNumber();
    int getQuantity();
    double getCost();
    double getTotalCost();




};

#endif //PROGRAM6_INVENTORY_H
```

Inventory.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Inventory.h"
using namespace std;

Inventory :: Inventory()
{
    itemNumber = 0;
    quantity = 0;
    cost = 0;
    totalCost = 0;
}

Inventory ::Inventory(int itemNumber, int quantity, double cost)
{
    setItemNumber(itemNumber);
    setQuantity(quantity);
    setCost(cost);
    setTotalCost();
}

void Inventory ::setItemNumber(int theItemNumber)
{
    if (theItemNumber > 0)
    {
        itemNumber = theItemNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You entered " << theItemNumber << " as your item number. Only positive numbers are accepted"<<endl;
    }
}

void Inventory ::setQuantity(int quantityOfItems)
{
    cout << "Setting quantity to " << quantityOfItems << endl;
    if (quantityOfItems > 0)
    {
        quantity = quantityOfItems;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You entered " << quantityOfItems << " as your item quantity. Only positive numbers are accepted"
             << endl;
    }
}

void Inventory ::setCost(double costOfItems)
{
    if (costOfItems > 0)
    {
        cost = costOfItems;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You entered " << costOfItems << " item cost. Only positive numbers are accepted" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}

void Inventory ::setTotalCost()
{
    int itemCount = getQuantity();
    double itemCost = getCost();
    totalCost = itemCost * itemCount;

}

int Inventory ::getItemNumber()
{
    return itemNumber;
}
int Inventory ::getQuantity()
{
    return quantity;
}
double Inventory ::getCost()
{
    return cost;
}
double Inventory ::getTotalCost()
{
    return totalCost;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Demonstrating the default constructor...

Item number: 0

Quantity   : 0

Cost       : 0.00

Total Cost : 0.00

Demonstrating the overloaded constructor...

Item number: 124

Quantity   : 12

Cost       : 84.95

Total Cost : 1019.40


Demonstrating the "set" functions...

Item number: 243

Quantity   : 50

Cost       : 9.50

Total Cost : 1019.40


Demonstrating the input validation functions...

You entered -1 as your item number. Only positive numbers are accepted

You entered -1 as your item quantity. Only positive numbers are accepted

You entered -1.00 item cost. Only positive numbers are accepted
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: `sertTotalCost` is a `public` function.  It must have been made `public` for a reason, that reason is that it can be called by code outside of the class.  Why didn't you just simply call `setTotalCost`?  If it were a `private` or `protected` function, then it is understandable to ask "how to call the function", but it isn't either of those -- it is `public`.

Comment: This is for my c++ course and the main.cpp code was provided to us, and we are not allowed to change any of it. But I do agree with you that calling the setTotalCost would not the most sensible action but unfortunately am not allowed to do that.

Comment: Then the purpose of `setTotalCost` is that it serves no purpose.  It isn't called in `main` anywhere, and is just unnecessary noise.  The `getTotalCost` should be the function doing the calculation, since `main` makes use of it.

Comment: The only time I use setTotalCost is during the constructor. Inventory()

Comment: Well that makes my point.  It is just a wheel-spinning exercise calling `setTotalCost`.  It isn't used in `main`, and the only time that total cost means anything is in the call to `getTotalCost`.  Thus it is `getTotalCost` that should be driving the calculation.

Comment: per my instructions///setTotalCost : Calculates the total inventory cost for the item (quantity
times cost) and stores the result in totalCost./////////getTotalCost:Returns the value in totalCost.///But I see where you are coming from , I am almost sure he either forgot to add the setTotalCost to his main, or I am missing something :) Thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for what I see, you do not call setTotalCost() after change the other variable. It will not happen automatically. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I know but is there a way of avoiding using a new seTotalCost() and make it so the constructor gets called again? Or does the constructor only get invoked when values are passed to it directly and not through the setters?

Comment: Constructor is only called when the object is first created. @KianO'Ryan

Comment: If you don't want to change main, you can change the setter, call setTotalCost() after changing other variables.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to make it so getTotalCost() returns the correct value without a setTotalCost() being explicitly called after the inputs to that value are updated. There are two ways that you can do this - you can have the setters for the inputs call that setter, or you can not store the value totalCost at all and recalculate every time you call getTotalCost().

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I per my instruction I need separate get and set totalcosts:///setTotalCost : Calculates the total inventory cost for the item (quantity times cost) and stores the result in totalCost./////////getTotalCost:Returns the value in totalCost.///

Comment: Right - so you need to call setTotalCost() at the end of the setters for the inputs.